# SPARQL types convert uri to/from literal

Tags: sparql, sparqlwrapper

I want to write a cross ontologies request, so it takes information from two ontologies per say onto1 and onto2:

```
select x y z where {
x onto1:hasY y
y onto2:hasZ Z
}
```

the problem is that the y differs in term of uri, from onto1 you get this y

```
http://uri1.com/yis#y
```

from onto2 you get this one:

```
http://uri2.com/yis#y
```

I tried to change one of the two uris but if you change it to the other, it doesn't work for its own triplet..

what I did is a bind to get rid of the uri1 and a concat to insert uri2 in it..

but then the type of the returned json changes from uri to literal! is there a way to change the type from literal to uri??

---

**update**

the returned json is : `{"type": "uri" , "value": "http://uri1...}`
and `{"type": "literal" , "value": "http://uri1...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just discovered the `URI` command. To solve my problem just add this to the concat function:

```
uri(fn:concat("http://uri2.com/#", "y1"))
```

It works for me, I can SPARQL from two different ontologies using a common class.